# Optimising pandas loop on a large dataframe while needing to limit the rows the loop performs on

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, optimization

I have a very large dataframe (around 8 million rows) with the following structure. it has been sorted by code and date and df.head() looks like this:

```
    code    date    open    high    low close   volume
0   1AD 20160822    0.305   0.31    0.26    0.28    312489
1   1AD 20160823    0.28    0.28    0.27    0.27    66638
2   1AD 20160824    0.27    0.27    0.255   0.26    161883
3   1AD 20160825    0.255   0.255   0.24    0.24    120307
4   1AD 20160826    0.225   0.225   0.22    0.22    109000
```

there are 5160 unique codes in the database each with varying date ranges.

What I am trying to do is add to this dataframe or create a new one, with  another column for % change (and after i would like to add the difference too) of the figures in the close column. currently the way I have coded this is by:

creating a variable that holds all the unique codes

```
y = df.code.unique()
```

and then creating an empty data frame to append new values too later:

```
dfchng = pd.DataFrame(data=d, columns=
['code','date','open','high','low','close','volume'])
dfchng.drop(dfchng.index, inplace=True)
dfchng.head()

code    date    open    high    low close   volume
```

and then creating a loop which, for each code will create a new dataframe which only holds the data for the individual code and will perform pct_change() on it, this is then appended to the dfchng dataframe i created earlier.

```
for i in y:
    dfiter = df[(df.code == str(i))]
    dfiter[['change_%']] = dfiter[['close']].pct_change()
    dfchng = dfchng.append(dfiter)
```

the reason i have done things this way is because i need to only calculate the change within each unique code, so I can't iterate over the original dataframe without getting incorrect values where one unique codes records end and another begins unless there is a method i don't know about.

the problem I have is that this has taken so far over 10 hours to run and is still going, I know of methods such as .apply() and .iterrows() but I'm not sure how i can apply them in this case. I've tried a few different things to get to this point now but I'm not really sure how to move forward and optimise this loop to perform quicker.

ultimately the end goal for this process is a dataframe that looks like this

```
    change_%    close   code    date    high    low open    volume
0        NaN    0.280   1AD 20160822    0.31    0.26    0.305   312489
1   -0.035714   0.270   1AD 20160823    0.28    0.27    0.28    66638
```

which i can put back into my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` + `pct_change`

```
df['change%']=df.groupby('code').close.pct_change()
df
Out[128]: 
  code      date   open   high    low  close  volume   change%
0  1AD  20160822  0.305  0.310  0.260   0.28  312489       NaN
1  1AD  20160823  0.280  0.280  0.270   0.27   66638 -0.035714
2  2AD  20160824  0.270  0.270  0.255   0.26  161883       NaN
3  2AD  20160825  0.255  0.255  0.240   0.24  120307 -0.076923
4  2AD  20160826  0.225  0.225  0.220   0.22  109000 -0.083333
```

Data input

```
df
Out[130]: 
  code      date   open   high    low  close  volume
0  1AD  20160822  0.305  0.310  0.260   0.28  312489
1  1AD  20160823  0.280  0.280  0.270   0.27   66638
2  2AD  20160824  0.270  0.270  0.255   0.26  161883
3  2AD  20160825  0.255  0.255  0.240   0.24  120307
4  2AD  20160826  0.225  0.225  0.220   0.22  109000
```

Comment: That's perfect, I'm new to pandas and wasn't aware that existed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jisket yw happy coding